# How to modify mean of std::poisson_distribution in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, stl, scope

How to modify mean of [std::poisson_distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/poisson_distribution/) in C++?

There is a global variable `std::poisson_distribution<int> distribution(mean);`. Somehow its mean should be defined from input (within a function), while it is used in another function. Is it possible that I can modify its mean after declaring and initializing it? Or is it possible that I can declare it as a global variable and initalize it (by "calling" its constructor) within a function?

I know I can pass the mean parameter to the functions actually call the Poisson generator. However, since the functions calling the Poisson generator are within a loop, this may lead to creating a generator multiple times or it may make program structure very complicate.

```
std::poisson_distribution<int> distribution(mean);
std::default_random_engine rand_generator;
int flag = 1;

void main()
{
  if (flag==1)
  {
    double poisson_mean;
    cin >> poisson_mean;
    // can I initialize poisson here using poisson_mean?
  }
  else
  {  }  // that is poisson is never used
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    func_do_sth();  // Poisson might be used in this function.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use assignment:

```
distribution = std::poisson_distribution<int>(poisson_mean);
```

or `param()`:

```
using param_t = std::poisson_distribution<int>::param_type;
distribution.param(param_t{poisson_mean});
```